# Shinyapps.io on safari browser cannot connect to server "localhost "

Tags: r, shiny, localhost, shinyapps

I've created a basic app in shiny that connects and uploads data to a shared googlesheet. The app works fine locally, however when I try to run it in a web browser, it won't upload any data.

The problem seems pretty straight forward. Using shiny apps.io I can view the apps logs, and it identifies that I need to provide the app permission, (specifically shinyapps and tidyverse) to upload data to google sheets, which is authorized by google sheets. This is no problem as I went through the same process on my own machine locally:

```
1) I'm running on a Mac, OSX Mojave v 10.14.2 
2) I've enabled web sharing via the terminal with sudo apachectl start (I think that's all it took?)
3) I've scoured similar problems on here. 
4) The app opens and uploads data when I "view in browser" from the RStudio IDE
5) I wanted to try Shiny Server, however apparently they haven't written anything for Macs yet that doesn't have to built from source, which is way beyond my level.
6) The google sheet is published to the web as well.
```

This is the provided message from shinyapps.io logs

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:37073
2019-01-15T14:33:32.976569+00:00 shinyapps[636194]: Adding .httr-oauth to .gitignore
2019-01-15T14:33:33.012405+00:00 shinyapps[636194]: Please point your browser to the following url: 
2019-01-15T14:33:33.010168+00:00 shinyapps[636194]: Waiting for authentication in browser...
2019-01-15T14:33:33.010485+00:00 shinyapps[636194]: Press Esc/Ctrl + C to abort
2019-01-15T14:33:33.012759+00:00 shinyapps[636194]: "This is the provided URL"

I then go to the provided URL, that takes me to a accounts.google page that asks me to provide authentication to a specific google account, which I do.
```

I then receive this error from safari:

```
Safari can't open the page "the provided URL" because safari cannot connect to the server "localhost"
```

I would basically like this app to be used only by the allowed google account which is a shared one and be able to upload from at most 3 different machines that are windows, Any help appreciated!

Comment: Is this problem occurring when hosted in the browser or when fully published (or both)?

Comment: @Chabo Just when hosted in the browser, it is fully published in shinyapps.io.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a temporary work around, in my code since I take advantage of the google sheets package in R, it as a function called:

```
gs_title("worksheet title")
```

this allows the app to identify the worksheet that has been given access to the app, however this is a problem when uploading the app online, I used a different function called:

```
gs_url("worksheet URL as copied from search bar")
```

It passes the url of the worksheet apparently bypassing the local server problem, and allowing me to open the app from other machines.